# I can get only empty space character from php to android

Tags: php, android

Please see the following code. When I use `""` in `php` and be sent to android, the following condition can to run:

```
   // Show response on activity
        String text2 = "";
        boolean check = text.equals(text2);
        if(check == true)
        { String display;
            display = (String)getText(R.string.display);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
else {textView.setText(text);}
```

**And**

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = urldecode($_POST['username']);
    $login = urldecode($_POST['login']);
    if(empty($username) || empty($login)) {
    $display = "";
    echo $display;
    }}
```

in codes above, when I use `$display = "";` the empty space character be sent to `text` object and because also `text2 = ""` the Toast class displays the `R.string.display`.

But when I use the characters such as `text` or another characters that are not like the empty space character (`""`), while the `$username` or the `$login` are empty, in the following code, the Toast class can not work and instead, the `else {textView.setText(text);}` works.

```
   // Show response on activity
        String text2 = "text";
        boolean check = text.equals(text2);
        if(check == true)
        { String display;
            display = (String)getText(R.string.display);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
else {textView.setText(text);}
```

**And**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$username = urldecode($_POST['username']);
$login = urldecode($_POST['login']);
if(empty($username) || empty($login)) {
$is = "text";
echo $is;
}}
 ?>
```

**Full-function form**

```
   public  void  GetText()  throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        // Get user defined values
        name = username.getText().toString();
        pass   = password.getText().toString();


        // Create data variable for sent values to server

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("login", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");

        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        // Send data
        try
        {

            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/example.php");

            // Send POST data request

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


            text = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                reader.close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }

        // Show response on activity
        String text2 = "text";
        boolean check = text.equals(text2);
        if(check == true)
        { String display;
            display = (String)getText(R.string.display);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
else {textView.setText(text);}
    }}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're doing the request from android to php to get that string? i suspect this has something to do with how you're getting the response string.

Comment: Additionally, please don't compare boolean values to `true` or `false`. It's very redundant.

Comment: @ iismathwizard , I updated my post. thank you.

Comment: change this line `String text2 = "text";` to this `String text2 = "text\n";` and let me know if it works

Comment: `.... empty space character ...`. Such characters do not exist to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop you're appending a `\n` to each line. That means, that when you read in the string `"text"` it'll actually read in `"text\n"`. Just change the string you're comparing too to `"text\n"` and it should work.

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;

// Read Server Response
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    // Append server response in string
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}

...

// Show response on activity
String text2 = "text\n";
```